# http new request with POST method value is blank

Tags: http, go, post

I am using below code to for POST method:

```
postData := url.Values{}
postData.Set("login_id", "test1")
postData.Set("api_key", "test2")

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST","http://example.com", strings.NewReader(postData.Encode()))

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
logger.Info(string(body))
os.Exit(3)
```

Values are not being set. When I checked with this: `logger.Info(req.PostFormValue("login_id"))` there is a blank value. How can I debug/solve this issue?

Comment: are url values not used in get request instead of post requests?

Comment: @Pizzalord: What do you mean? This is the method in http package: `func NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error) `

Comment: You need to "tell" the request what the content type is, ie  `req.Header.Set("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` https://play.golang.org/p/nVVe_p6P8ph

Comment: @mkopriva That's the answer, post it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the request's `Content-Type` with `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`.

```
postData := url.Values{}
postData.Set("login_id", "test1")
postData.Set("api_key", "test2")

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:8080/", strings.NewReader(postData.Encode()))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

req.Header.Set("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
fmt.Println(req.PostFormValue("login_id"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nVVe_p6P8ph

Answer (score 1):

> When I checked with this: `logger.Info(req.PostFormValue("login_id"))` there is a blank value.

Of course they are. But that does not mean these values are not sent.

`PostFormValue` is used to access the form values on a **server** `Request` and not on a **client** `Request` as your's `req`.

Comment: From server side as well I am getting response that I am not providing required values.

Comment: @RonakPatel, you have to debug the server then. Your request is correct and you can verify that with [httputil.DumpRequestOut](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut). Setting the Content-Type header as suggested by mkopriva is probably a good start though.

Answer (score 0):

PostForm is below.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.PostForm(URL, url.Values{"login_id": {"test1"}, "api_key": {"test2"}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err == nil {
        str := string(respBody)
        println(str)
    }
}
```